# Как выводить несколько типов уведомлений в статус баре Android?

Tags: java, android

В моём приложении приходят пуш уведомления. Они выводятся в статус баре. Но каждое новое уведомление заменяет старое. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы они были разделены на типы. Например, все уведомления для комментариев пусть заменяют друг друга, а уведомления, к примеру, о лайках, пусть заменяют только уведомления о лайках, но не лезут в уведомления о комментах. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого уведомления (Notification) есть `ID`, кторый вы назначаете при его создании и отображении. Вам надо реализовать логику как раз в этом месте и назначать уведомлениям разные ID-шники.

Comment: Да, пока ждал ответа, сам нашёл уже) NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(push_id, noBuilder.build()); - вот этот push_id как раз и есть тот самый ID). Но спасибо за ответ.